# Inserting string (character by character) into a larger string

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to insert a string by replacing a substring in the (original) string with a new string (toInsert). The start parameter is the starting position of the substring I want to replace. Note: This is part of a larger program but I am just trying to get this function to work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ROW 5
#define COLUMN 81

void insertString(char original[], int start, int length, char toInsert[]){

char buffer[COLUMN];
int i = 0;

for (i=0; i<strlen(original); ++i){
    if (i>=start){
        buffer[i] = toInsert[i];
    }
    else{
        buffer[i] = original[i];
    }
}

buffer[strlen(buffer)-1] = '\0';



printf("%s\n", buffer);



return;
}

int main()
{
char rep[COLUMN] = "very";
char sub[COLUMN] = "are";

char buf[ROW][COLUMN] = {
    {"How are you doing"}


};
int len = strlen(sub);
int start = 4;

insertString(buf[0], start, len, rep);



return 0;
}
```

The problem is it only prints "How".

I want it to print "How very you doing"

Also, I have tried using strcpy but that just gives errors/warnings (something to do with pointers and I don't want to deal with pointers because I have not learned about them yet.)

Comment: Well, it is difficult to use strings without dealing with pointers. ;-)

Comment: aha I understand but is there way to fix this problem without them?

Comment: No, you are already using strings. However, this is not important here. Please boil down your problem without having arrays of arrays. You do not need that to describe your problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: With `void insertString(char original[], int start, int length, char toInsert[])`, `original` and `toInsert` are pointers.  Are you certain that "don't want to deal with pointers"?

Comment: Like I said this is part of a larger program and I tried adding in the * or whatever and it gave me an error because i'm actually calling this function from another function (not from main) Therefore adding pointers would mess my entire program up

Comment: You are using `strlen` on `buffer` which isn't null-terminated at the point of call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function does not make great sense because it neither enlarge or shrink the original string though it has to do this.

And moreover it has undefined behavior due to this if statement because when `i` is equal to or greater than `start` you can access the memory beyond the string `toInsert` using the index `i`.

```
if (i>=start){
    buffer[i] = toInsert[i];
}
```

It is simpler to write the function using standard C functions.

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char * replaceString( char *s1, size_t pos, size_t n, const char *s2 )
{
    size_t n1 = strlen( s1 );

    if ( pos < n1 )
    {
        size_t n2 = strlen( s2 );

        if ( n != n2 )
        {

            memmove( s1 + pos + n2, s1 + pos + n, n1 - pos - n + 1 );
        }

        memcpy( s1 + pos, s2, n2 );
    }

    return s1;
}


int main(void) 
{
    {
        char s1[100] = "ab1111cd";
        const char *s2 = "22";

        puts( replaceString( s1, 2, 4 , s2 ) );
    }

    {
        char s1[100] = "ab11cd";
        const char *s2 = "2222";

        puts( replaceString( s1, 2, 2 , s2 ) );
    }

    {
        char s1[100] = "ab11cd";
        const char *s2 = "22";

        puts( replaceString( s1, 2, 2 , s2 ) );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ab22cd
ab2222cd
ab22cd
```

If to insert this code block

```
{
    char s1[100] = "How are you doing";
    const char *s2 = "very";

    puts( replaceString( s1, 4, 3 , s2 ) );
}
```

in the demonstrative program you will get the output

```
How very you doing
```

Comment: Never mind I got it to work. Thank you again mr. Vlad this works but hopefully it will work in my entire program

Comment: You sir are amazing it works in my program thank you

Comment: @JohnSmith I am glad to hear this.:)

Comment: Hey if you don't mind me asking, what exactly does the memmove do?

Comment: @JohnSmith If the inserted substring is greater or less than the substring to be substituted then redundant symbols should be removed from the string and the function moves the tail pare of the string accordingly.