# How can I replace memcpy() with an equivalent strcat()?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memcpy, strcat

I have the following code that works properly inserting a substring into a specific part of the original string. How can I do the same thing using `strcat()` instead of `memcpy()`?

```
void insertString(char original[], int start, int length, char toInsert[]){
  size_t insertlen = strlen(toInsert);
  size_t origlen = strlen(original);
  char *m = malloc(origlen - length + insertlen);
  memcpy(m, &original[0], start);
  memcpy(m+start, &toInsert[0], insertlen);
  memcpy(m+start+insertlen, &original[start+length], origlen-length+insertlen);
  strcpy(original,m);
}
```

Where `char original[]` is the original string, `int start` is the element which the substring should start at, `int length` is the length of the substring being removed from `original[]` and `char toInsert[]` is the substring being inserted.

Example to clarify :

ex. if
`original[] = default string 1`,
`start = 5`,
`length = 6`,
`toInsert[] = hello world`

the resuling `m` would equal 'defauhello worlding 1' since the substring being replaced in this example is 'lt str' starting at 5 chracters in and is 6 characters long. How can I do the same thing with `strcat()` instead of `memcpy()`?

Comment: It depends whether you have any other constraints. The easiest would be to allocate a new memory buffer, init it to an empty string, strncat the original up to start, strncat the toInsert, strncat the original from start+length and then strcpy back into original.

Comment: You need `strncat()`, not `strcat()`.

Comment: BTW `char *m = malloc(origlen - length + insertlen);` --> `char *m = malloc(origlen - length + insertlen + 1);` and You forgot null-terminator.

Comment: A question the same function signature: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40663835/inserting-string-character-by-character-into-a-larger-string. Same homework?

Comment: Thank you kaylum I have changed it and it works perfectly!

Comment: The way function signature is written, it may not be possible. The only way it's workable if you do not need to malloc. That is when the new string you are trying to insert has a length less than ```length```.

Comment: It must be said that using `strcat` here (as almost always) is a performance pessimization - instead of doing `strlen` just once for each string and them going straight in the correct positions, you are going to make `strcat` look again for the string end each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use strncat and do it in the below way. But, please note that the below doesn't handle error conditions and other constraints which you have as a part of this problem.

```
void insertString(char original[], int start, int length, char toInsert[]){
  size_t insertlen = strlen(toInsert);
  size_t origlen = strlen(original);
  size_t newBuffLen = origlen - length + insertlen + 1
  char *m = malloc(newBuffLen);
  memset(m, 0, newBuffLen);
  strncat(m, original, start);
  strncat(m, toInsert, insertlen);
  strncat(m, original + start+ length, origlen-start-length);
  strcpy(original,m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have replaced it with the following and it works perfectly

```
void insertString(char original[], int start, int length, char toInsert[]){
  size_t insertlen = strlen(toInsert);
  size_t origlen = strlen(original);
  char holder[origlen - length + insertlen];
  strcpy(holder,"");
  strncat(holder,original,start);
  strcat(holder,toInsert);
  strncat(holder, &original[start+length], origlen-length+insertlen);
  strcpy(original,holder);
}
```

Thank you all for your help!